# CASE Statement error with ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am struggling as to why the commented out code below (`AND ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE IS NULL`) is erroring with the error - `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` when I uncomment this additional condition in the `CASE` statement. Both `UNIT_OF_ISSUE` and `PRIMARY_UOM_CODE` are both String type fields.  If I just use `WHEN ESIB.PRIMARY_UOM_CODE = 'EA'` it works, so I don't understand why the `AND...` condition is causing issues.

I realize I can add the entire case expression to the GROUP BY but I would like to see if there are any other options here, and why this is occuring.

```sql
SELECT ESIB.ITEM_NUMBER, 
       ESIT.LONG_DESCRIPTION, 
       IOP.ORGANIZATION_CODE, 
       isub.secondary_inventory SUBINVENTORY_CODE, 
       CASE WHEN SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY) IS NULL 
       THEN  0         
       WHEN ESIB.PRIMARY_UOM_CODE = 'EA' --AND ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE IS NULL
       THEN SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY)          
       ELSE SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY) / INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE  
       END ONHAND_QTY
      ,ESIB.PRIMARY_UOM_CODE ONHAND_UOM
FROM   EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ESIB
       INNER JOIN EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL ESIT
       ON ESIB.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ESIT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 
          AND ESIB.ORGANIZATION_ID = ESIT.ORGANIZATION_ID 
       INNER JOIN INV_ORG_PARAMETERS IOP
       ON ESIB.ORGANIZATION_ID = IOP.ORGANIZATION_ID
          AND INVENTORY_FLAG = 'Y' 
          AND isub.organization_id = iop.organization_id 
GROUP BY
       ESIB.ITEM_NUMBER, 
       ESIT.LONG_DESCRIPTION, 
       IOP.ORGANIZATION_CODE, 
       isub.secondary_inventory, 
       ESIB.PRIMARY_UOM_CODE,
        INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE
```

Comment: I don't see a FROM clause. And `SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY) / INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE` you can't divide an aggregated column by an unaggregated column.

Comment: Well it does the division fine, that is not the condition I have having issues with anyways.

Comment: @Nick That is precisely the problem though. All columns must be in the GROUP BY or aggregated via an aggregate formula. You *may* be able to get away with sticking it in the GROUP BY, but I really doubt that's your intention. If you can share sample data and desired results then we can help out. Otherwise we only can guess at your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause:

Some options are:

1. Add `ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE`  to the `GROUP BY` clause.
2. Wrap `ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE` in an aggregation function (such as `MAX`, `MIN`, `COUNT` etc.):

   ```sql
   CASE
   WHEN SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY) IS NULL 
   THEN 0         
   WHEN ESIB.PRIMARY_UOM_CODE = 'EA'
   AND  MAX(ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE) IS NULL
   THEN SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY)          
   ELSE SUM(IOQD.PRIMARY_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY)
         / INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE
   END AS ONHAND_QTY
   ```

Comment: @MTO The issue is with the Commented out code (AND ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE IS NULL). When I uncomment that code and attempt to use it I get the Group By Error. Removing the ELSE division statement entirely does not resolve the error... I actually already hade the INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE in the GROUP BY, just didnt include it above. The issue is with the commented out code causing the error when I  try to use it.

Comment: @Nick A similar answer applies to `ESIB.UNIT_OF_ISSUE` as to `INTRACONV.CONVERSION_RATE`. Either add it to the `GROUP BY` clause or wrap it in an aggregation function.

Comment: Oh I see it now! The other columns were already grouped on. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!